# Why cpanel emails go to spam?

Tags: email, dns, hosting, cpanel

Please I create some emails in my Cpanel domain
but when I'm sending some emails it's automatically goes to spam.

What is the problem and how we can fix it?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your server IP address is not blacklisted.

you can check your IP against a bunch of blacklists here:

http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check

The following document is a good place to start in terms of preventing users from sending out SPAM and enabling the options to better detect when it happens:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Prevent+Email+Abuse

Additionally, the following thread offer some useful tips for investigating the source of SPAM messages:

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/need-to-catch-the-spamming-source.604567/

https://forums.cpanel.net/resources/why-didnt-my-email-get-delivered-or-where-did-my-email-go.387/

Comment: Thank you i solve the problem by fixing the dns recordes in the cpanel

Comment: @Ma7 can you tell me how you fix it please?

Comment: Check DKIM, DMARC, and SPF records for preventing the emails from going into the spam folder.